# Apache Spark type mismatch of the same type (String)

Tags: scala, types, apache-spark, mismatch

EDIT: Answer:  **It was a JAR file that created a conflict!**
The related post is: [Must include log4J, but it is causing errors in Apache Spark shell. How to avoid errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29375027/must-include-log4j-but-it-is-causing-errors-in-apache-spark-shell-how-to-avoid)

Doing the following:

```
val numOfProcessors:Int = 2
val filePath:java.lang.String = "s3n://somefile.csv"
var rdd:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[java.lang.String] = sc.textFile(filePath, numOfProcessors)
```

I get

```
    error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
       var rdd:org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[java.lang.String] = sc.textFile(filePath, numOfProcessors)
```

---

EDIT:  Second case

```
val numOfProcessors = 2
val filePath = "s3n://somefile.csv"
var rdd = sc.textFile(filePath, numOfProcessors) //OK!

def doStuff(rdd: RDD[String]): RDD[String] = {rdd}

doStuff(rdd)
```

I get:

```
error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[String]
              doStuff(rdd)
                      ^
```

No comment...

Any ideas why I get this error ?

Comment: Why are you using java.lang.String? What happens if you use just String consistently?

Comment: I guess you've some issues with your imports. Those repeated paths indicate something is wrong

Comment: Exactly the same thing, I will edit the question so people go not get confused

Comment: OK I will try with the minimum imports

Comment: Yes, most likely the imports!  I will investigate this further before calling it a final answer.

Comment: It was the JAR file that created a conflict.... hmm... this might be a bit more difficult to solve.

Comment: I guess I had the same problem. I got out of this  "jar problem" by doing mvn clean compile

Answer (score 2):

The problem was a JAR file that created a conflict.