# Spark type mismatch for exact type

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib

While trying the Naive Bayes example [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/mllib-naive-bayes.html) I encounter this problem on Spark 1.4 on Ubuntu. I've seen posts with similar issues where the fix was fixing a jar mismatch (through Maven) but in this case, the classes in question come packaged with Spark so I'm not sure how to proceed.

```
scala> val model = NaiveBayes.train(training, lambda = 1.0, modelType = "multinomial")
<console>:46: error: type mismatch;
 found   : org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint]
 required: org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[org.apache.spark.mllib.regression.LabeledPoint]
       val model = NaiveBayes.train(training, lambda = 1.0, modelType = "multinomial")
                                    ^
```

Also note the really long chain of class type:

```
org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD
```

Could this be some classloader bug? Perhaps its looking for org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD but finds the wrong string (though the class is actually correct).

Related:
[Apache Spark type mismatch of the same type (String)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29371592/apache-spark-type-mismatch-of-the-same-type-string)

Answer (score 0):

Turns out importing the same library in spark-shell somehow causes corruption of the names (i.e appending the names). By using Roy's advice of turning it off and on again, I got this to work but I encounter another problem:

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: empty String
        at sun.misc.FloatingDecimal.readJavaFormatString(FloatingDecimal.java:1020)
        at java.lang.Double.parseDouble(Double.java:540)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringLike$class.toDouble(StringLike.scala:232)
        at scala.collection.immutable.StringOps.toDouble(StringOps.scala:31)
        at $line22.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:28)
        at $line22.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$1.apply(<console>:28)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$$anonfun$map$1.apply(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.IndexedSeqOptimized$class.foreach(IndexedSeqOptimized.scala:33)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.foreach(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at scala.collection.TraversableLike$class.map(TraversableLike.scala:244)
        at scala.collection.mutable.ArrayOps$ofRef.map(ArrayOps.scala:108)
        at $line22.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:28)
        at $line22.$read$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$iwC$$anonfun$1.apply(<console>:26)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.next(Iterator.scala:328)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$14.hasNext(Iterator.scala:389)
        at scala.collection.Iterator$$anon$11.hasNext(Iterator.scala:327)
        at org.apache.spark.util.collection.ExternalSorter.insertAll(ExternalSorter.scala:199)
        at org.apache.spark.shuffle.sort.SortShuffleWriter.write(SortShuffleWriter.scala:56)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.ShuffleMapTask.runTask(ShuffleMapTask.scala:41)
        at org.apache.spark.scheduler.Task.run(Task.scala:70)
        at org.apache.spark.executor.Executor$TaskRunner.run(Executor.scala:213)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```